# Flask app returns a "502: Bad Gateway" because Google Sloud SDK thinks the port is in use (it's [probably] not)

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a fairly simple Flask app with a couple views using Google's App Engine. As far as I know, nothing is wrong with the Flask code itself - it runs just fine on a local port. The problem, however, occurs when I cd into the project directory and run "gcloud app deploy." The app deploys without any errors and returns a 502 code when I go into the .appspot.com domain reserved for the app.

I was a little confused, so I ran "gcloud app logs tail." This is the message that is displayed on repeat in the logs:

```
* Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
* Environment: production
WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Debug mode: on
* Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[2019-01-06 23:55:00 +0000] [240] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
[2019-01-06 23:55:00 +0000] [240] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('', 8081)
[2019-01-06 23:55:00 +0000] [240] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2019-01-07 23:55:01 +0000] [240] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('', 8081)
```

Running "netstat -ano" shows no processes that are actually using port 8081. Running netstat and killing whatever process was using the occupied port was suggested in a post with a problem similar to mine. However, there's literally nothing using 8081 here.

"main" is main.py, a file that creates an app, registers all the blueprints, and runs the app with

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

I'm totally new to using the App Engine - am I missing something? Anyone know where to start?

Comment: Can you share your app.yaml file? (Make sure that there is no sensitive information). As well, you mentioned that you are using the netstat command in your machine to see which ports were being in use, however when the application is deployed, it is not running locally in your computer, but on an instance in App Engine, so unless you can access the machine running your app (I don't believe it's possible to do so), and run the command in its environment, this command doesn't help at all.

Comment: I keep getting an error when trying to edit in the `app.yaml` file in the original post, so here's the code, if you can make it out. I don't think I changed much from the [Google App Engine tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/python-standard-env):

runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: .*
 script: auto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the issue on my side, and I have been able to reproduce the error message.

The problem is that in your main.py file, you are calling the line `app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)` from the root of your script.

You should have this line inside your `main.py`, as shown here:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

What this [conditioning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) does, is to make sure that its nested statements are only executed when the file is directly executed, i.e. running `python main.py` in your local computer.

What the [app.run](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.run) statement does, is to execute the Flask application in a local development server, that is created at the host direction (in your case "0.0.0.0", which in flask means that the application is exposed externally), and in the specific port (which defaults to 5000).

You are using gunicorn as a entrypoint to the application, and you are pointing it to the `app` object inside the `main` script, as defined in the `app.yaml` file. But since the flask app is already running in another server, created by the `app.run` statement, gunicorn is not able to point to the application, hence it's not able to serve requests.

In short, don't execute `app.run` when deploying to App Engine.

Comment: Thank you so much! The app runs perfectly now :)

EDIT: And if I shouldn't use `app.run` when deploying, what would be the "correct" way of running the app?

Comment: More than not using, I meant to make sure not to execute `run.app` when deploying the app. Nesting this statement inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` is the correct way to ignore this statement when the app is deployed, but running it when you test the app locally with `python main.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine uses the gunicorn webprocess to serve the app, so app.run() in the main file only runs locally and does not change anything to the webserver, unless you specify an entrypoint.

Are you specifying an entrypoint in your `app.yaml`? Try adding the following line to your app.yaml and adding gunicorn in your `requirements.txt`.

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Comment: I am indeed specifying an entrypoint, in exactly the same way you suggested. I also have gunicorn in my `requirements.txt`.